# Need to have a longer image description

Tags: css, popup, caption

I'm currently making a simple and basic website for my project. I am using a free website template, where there is a gallery of images that when clicked are displayed in a bigger size with a title below. How can I change it so that instead of the short title a description is displayed instead?

**CSS**

```
.poptrox-popup .caption {

            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5em;
            line-height: 5em;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: default;
            z-index: 1;
            font-size: 0.7em;
        }
```

Comment: can you share a snippet or live example of the template?

Comment: My guess is that `line-height: 5em;` is the deal-breaker here, causing the output to be restricted to one line of text only.